# The Kitchen Sink Cards in Bootstrap are not aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi my Bootstrap Kitchen sink cards are not aligning properly (Horizontally).

I tried some codes in CSS as well as Bootstrap(HTML).

CSS Code:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
```

Bootstrap code.

```
d-flex justify-content-center
```

Here is an Image of the webapp
[image: Here is an Image of the webapp]

I expected the cards to become Horizontally aligned properly but I didnt happen like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can modify your CSS code:

```
.card {
  height: 300px; /* set a fixed height for all cards */
  margin: 10px; /* add some margin to separate the cards */
}

.card-deck {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch; /* make all cards the same height */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

And here's an example of how you can modify your Bootstrap code:

```
<div class="card-deck justify-content-center">
  <div class="card">
    <!-- card content goes here -->
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <!-- card content goes here -->
  </div>
  <!-- add more cards as needed -->
</div>
```

Remember to replace the `<!-- card content goes here -->` placeholder with your actual card content.

I hope this helps you align your Bootstrap Kitchen sink cards properly!